# Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to set my  bootstrap datepicker's value to the current date, however, I am struggling with this error from jquery-ui:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'minDate')".
```

However, I do have this property:

```
$('#ExpectedCloseDate').bootstrapDP({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: "0",
        maxDate: "+30d",
    });
```

This is the way I am trying to set the datepicker value like:

```
$("#ExpectedCloseDate").datepicker("setDate", "0");
```

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it. I just set the input value to something like this and my code worked:

> val(newDate().toLocaleDateString());